# Android ProgressBar code seems to have errors

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I am using the following lines of code from the AndroidDevelopers website (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html):

```
ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this);
progressBar.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER));
progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
getListView().setEmptyView(progressBar);

// Must add the progress bar to the root of the layout
ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
root.addView(progressBar);
```

The line of code,

```
progressBar.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER));
```

seems to have an error, as no LayoutParams Constructor takes three arguments. I would like to have my progressbar at the center of the screen. Are there any fixes to the above code?

Answer (score 4):

It's just an import namespace problem. Use the import line below.

```
import android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams;
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually FrameLayout does.

`FrameLayout.LayoutParams(int width, int height, int gravity)`

> Creates anew set of layout parameters with the specified width, height and
>   weight.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.LayoutParams.html

Answer (score 0):

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
progressDialog.setTitle("MyMessage");
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
progressDialog.setMax(1000);
progressDialog.setMessage("MyMessage");
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
progressDialog.show();
progressDialog.setProgress(10);
```

you can also customize it using setView() method